# Anonymous users cannot see reusable content in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, anonymous-access

I have a SharePoint 2010 extranet (Enterprise Edition, fully service packed) which users can access anonymously. On some pages I expose the reusable content in custom web parts, using the code;

```
SPListItem reusableItem = reusableList.GetItemById(someId);
```

That exact line fails for some items for anonymous users, producing an exception '**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values**'. The exception indicates that the anonymous user cannot see the list item at all. I am not using any kind of impersonation, and the items in the reusable content list all inherit their permissions, which grants read access for anonymous users.

The SharePoint farm has a standard english installation, with a danish language pack on top. The extranet site is created in danish.

The items that produce the exception are the items that I create on the danish site. The three standard built-in items do not produce the exception when accessed by anonymous users.

I am guessing that the problem has to do with the language or culture of the anonymous user. One thing to notice is that the exception message is in english, not in danish, although the entire extranet site is in danish.

It could also be a matter of encoding. Perhaps the three built-in items use an english encoding, while any items I create on the site use danish encoding, including the three special danish characters for ae, oe and aa. The exception occurs regardless of whether I actually use the danish characters in the reusable content.

Does anyone have an idea why I get the exception when accessing any but the three built-in reusable content items?